# How to send oauth2 access_token in cookies ? (kong oauth2 plugin)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, kong

I am using Kong oauth2 plugin to handle authentication for my dash plotly app. Dash plotly does not allow the user to set a custom header for the requests and so it very difficult to add an authentication header to my requests.

These headers work perfectly for normal web pages
`"Authorization": "Bearer snakjdnjsbcksnbnddnndnsms"` or
`"authorization": "snakjdnjsbcksnbnddnndnsms"`

However, due to the limitation of Dash Plotly not allowing to set the headers I want to try to send the authorization token in a cookie.
I tried sending a cookie with the "authorization" key and corresponding value via my flask app, however I still get an unauthorized response.

Is this method even possible ? I saw that it works in loopback.token of nodejs using signed cookies. If so how can I achieve this ? Appreciate any help in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think, this is even feasible. As per OAuth 2.0 RFC, the access token should be passed as a bearer header.

> Typically, it involves
> using the HTTP "Authorization" request header field [RFC2617] with an
> authentication scheme defined by the specification of the access
> token type used, such as [RFC6750].

[Link to RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-48)